# Reading/Writing Text from Multiple Files to Master File

Tags: python

In the code below I'm trying to open a series of text files and copy their contents into a single file. I'm getting an error on the "os.write(out_file, line)" in which it asks me for an integer. I haven't defined what "line" is, so is that the problem? Do I need to specify somehow that "line" is a text string from the in_file? Also, I open the out_file through each iteration of the for-loop. Is that bad? Should I open it once at the beginning? Thanks!

```
import os
import os.path
import shutil

# This is supposed to read through all the text files in a folder and
# copy the text inside to a master file.

#   This defines the master file and gets the source directory
#   for reading/writing the files in that directory to the master file.

src_dir = r'D:\Term Search'
out_file = r'D:\master.txt'
files = [(path, f) for path,_,file_list in os.walk(src_dir) for f in file_list]

# This for-loop should open each of the files in the source directory, write
# their content to the master file, and finally close the in_file.

for path, f_name in files:
    open(out_file, 'a+')
    in_file = open('%s/%s' % (path, f_name), 'r')
    for line in in_file:
        os.write(out_file, line)
    close(file_name)
    close(out_file)

print 'Finished'
```

Comment: Also, I'm teaching myself python from books and such so I can do my research as a grad student so this question may be a tad on the beginner side of things. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend you to use os.path.join(path, f_name) to build up correctly the full path filename: in_file=open(os.path.join(path, f_name),'r')

Comment: It's been a while since I posted my question, but in coming back I noticed it was downvoted. Any recommendations on what I could do to ask my question better would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it wrong:

You did:

```
open(out_file, 'a+')
```

but that doesn't save the reference as a variable, so you have no way to access the file object you just created. What you need to do:

```
out_file_handle = open(out_file, 'a+')
...
out_file_handle.write(line)
...
out_file_handle.close()
```

Or, more pythonically:

```
out_filename = r"D:\master.txt"
...
with open(out_filename, 'a+') as outfile:
    for filepath in files:
        with open(os.path.join(*filepath)) as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())

print "finished"
```